# Drupal, CSS, Form Submit Button - styling gets lost after ajax

Tags: css, forms, drupal

How can I properly style the form submit button, specifically an "add to cart"?

The class is `.form-submit`, and the id is `#edit-submit`.

When I style it with the id, `#edit-submit`, the style lasts until ajax updates the form. The Submit button then looks the same as the rest of Drupal's buttons.

If I use the class to style, then for some reason it only accepts the height of the button, and ignores the rest of the styling.

Any advice?

Comment: In general I would not suggest the following, but if some library overwrites your styles and you have no control over it, maybe using `!important` for your styles helps.

Comment: The best way is to add your own class using hook_form_alter and use the same for styling. This way, it would not override other elements having default Drupal classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you have some conflicts in CSS.Will this work?

```
!important;
```

Example

```
.your_css_class
{
    height:500px !important;
}
```